# How to correctly check if an object implements an interface

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to implement custom behavior for certain objects.

For that, have my items (inheriting from QGraphicsItem) implement some interface.

```
class SomeParentItem 
{ 
    SomeParentItem(bool x) { x = true; } 
    void function1() {}
};
class SomeInterface
{
    virtual void function2() = 0;
};
class XYZItem : public QGraphicsXYZItem, public SomeParentItem, public SomeInterface
{
    XYZItem(bool x):SomeParentItem(x) {}
    virtual void function2() { x = false; }
};
class MPQItem : public QGraphicsMPQItem, public SomeParentItem
{
    MPQItem (bool x):SomeParentItem(x) {}
};
```

From outside, I was thinking that i just do

```
SomeInterface* item1 = dynamic_cast<SomeInterface*>(item);
if(item1 == NULL)
    item->function1(); 
else
    item1->function2();
```

Unfortunately this crashes... usually... so I was creating a flag to test, and if the flag was true, only then dare to cast.

But I kept thinking, it shouldn't crash. So I got brave and tried it again, this time in a QWidget child. Instead of crash I got

```
QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
```

It is the test `if(item1 == NULL)` that gives that message...

How do I check correctly if my item implements `SomeInterface` ?

Note: `item` cannot be null.

Comment: Just a note, if `item` is null, then you will call `function2()` on `item1` which will also be null.

Comment: `item` cannot be null

Comment: What kind of crash are you getting? Did you try to test `item` for null? That seems the only way it can crash. `dynamic_cast` is the normal way for testing an object for an interface implemented.

Comment: After fixing something on the widget itself, I am not getting an error anymore.. I can't explain why eliminating the test earlier also did not give an error... Thank you for looking at my question, but it seems I was troubleshooting the wrong problem based on symptoms

Answer (score 1):

There may be a compiler switch which disables run-time-type-information, in which case it would explain behaviour.  Otherwise item1 should only be non-null, if the dynamic_cast worked

Answer (score 0):

A simple generic template can make code more readable and simpler to implement.

```
template < class T > 
        bool is_SomeParentItem( T& P)                                                                                                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                                                                                                             
          if ( dynamic_cast<SomeParentItem*>(&P) ) 
              return true;                                                                                                                                             
          else 
              return false;                                                                                                                                                                               
        }

template < class T > 
        bool is_SomeInterface( T& I)                                                                                                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                                                                                                             
          if ( dynamic_cast<SomeInterface*>(&I) ) 
              return true;                                                                                                                                             
          else 
              return false;                                                                                                                                                                               
        }

template < class T >
    void function( T& X)
      {
         if ( isSomeInterface(X) )
         { 
             dynamic_cast<SomeInterface*>(&X)->function2();
             return;
         }

         if ( isSomeParentItem(X) )
             dynamic_cast<SomeParentItem*>(&X)->function1();
      }
```

You need the second function template to avoid trying to call
`function2` on a class that does not implement it.
if you try this:

```
 if ( isSomeInterface(instance) ) instance.function2();
```

on a class that does not implement function2, the compiler will
balk because it cannot bind to function2 for that instance, and that is 
correct but not intuitive because it looks like it would not be called from the left-to-right logic. However the compiler can not know at compile time what  `isSomeInterface` will return.

This technique is not considered by many to be a *"good style"* of programming because it can lead to C++ spaghetti and code bloat, and become difficult to maintain and debug.
`dynamic_cast` is usually used to differentiate same-named functions in a class hierarchy, specifically for *base-class vs subclass* methods, and in the case of multiple-inheritance with overlap of method signatures, to determinedly pick the correct method for the circumstance.

```
    // safe implements                                                                                                                                                                            
#define implements( C, I ) (    __extension__ ({                   \                                                                                                                          
        static bool impl=(dynamic_cast<I*>(&C))? true : false;     \                                                                                                                          
        impl;                                                      \                                                                                                                          
      })) 

     if ( implements( instance, SomeInterface ) ) ...
```

is a macro to check for interface compliance at runtime, if needed.
However, use sparingly.
If you are doing this more than once in a great while, your code *most likely* needs refactoring.

Answer (score -2):

What about something simple like:

```
class SomeInterface
{
    virtual void function2() = 0;
    virtual qint32 role() =0;
};
```

And returning a different int for a custom behavior ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and introduces dependencies on magic numbers to boot.